# Looking for an undergraduate research problem in algebraic geometry or algebraic number theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

I'm looking for a small research problem an undergraduate would be capable of after taking just an abstract algebra course, introductory algebraic geometry (at level of Miles Reid's book and Ideals, Varieties & Algorithms), and a course in number theory. Is there a website that would have a decent listing, or possibly a book one can recommend that may have small open research problems?

Comment: Open problems in algebraic geometry accessible to an advanced undergraduate seem scarce enough that I would keep any I thought of as trade secrets.  And at this moment I can't think of anything else mathematical I would keep as a trade secret!


Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is missing a crucial word in the first sentence (capable of ...). Is the missing word "understanding" or "solving"?

Anyway, here is a problem: Find the maximum number of points of a curve of genus $g$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$, for some values of $g,q$ for which this number is not known (check for values at http://www.manypoints.org/ )

Comment: @Felipe, I will be amazed if someone who knows algebraic geometry from the given sources can deal with it over a field not algebraically closed.  Also, Reid's book avoids Riemann-Roch, so genus will be tough to use  algebraically, let alone over finite fields.  There's always plane curves, but undergraduate research in these areas seems a dubious idea. 

Perhaps another crucial word is missing: *elementary* number theory or *algebraic* number theory? 